# fetch data from one python file into another

Tags: python, import

I am trying to break my Python script into multiple .py files. In `sf_opps.py` file I have all the login credentials and a query that fetches the data with REST API call. The data is stored in `sf_prod_data` variable. How can I access this variable that contains the data I need from another .py file?

I need to loop through the `sf_prod_data` and I don't want to use classes as all of my code are mostly loops, so need to know how to access the variables with stored data in it from different .py files.

I have tried:

```
import sf_opps
print(sf_prod_data)
```

`sf_prod_data is Undefined`

Comment: try `print(sf_opps.sf_prod_data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
from sf_opps import sf_prod_data
print(sf_prod_data)
```

or:

```
import sf_opps
print(sf_opps.sf_prod_data)
```

Further reading: python tutorial on [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Thank you @causaSui